# Questions about Autodesk Forge Viewer API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I couldn't find Forge Viewer API demo site and don't know what it looks like. I appreciate it if you have some experience using it and answer questions below.

1. Can you put markup comments on 3D models easily?
2. When you update comments, are they automatically saved right after you click some update button?
3. Can you delete 3D model data easily?
4. Is it mandatory to upload 3D model data to the Autodesk cloud server when you use the Forge Viewer? I don't want to put design data outside of my service but want to see 3D model on a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload any model and check with Viewer through viewer.autodesk.com

1. We have a few options for markups on documents. [this blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg) might be helpful. You can also take advantage of [sprites](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/sprites/) and [textgeometry](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-do-you-add-labels-forge-viewer) for labeling your models
2. Depending on the method you'll need to implement an algorithm to save, store and load your markups.
3. The data you see with Viewer is the SVF(2) generated by a translation from a source file. To modify the source file, you'll need to run a [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) job.
4. You need to upload your models to a bucket in order to trigger a translation, generating an SVF(2) that can be rendered with Viewer (refer here).
   Formats like [gltf](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/gltf-20-support-forge-viewer), [pdf, and dwf](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/dwf-and-pdf-support-forge-viewer) can be loaded without the need for translations.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! You say "The data you see with Viewer is the SVF(2) generated by a translation from a source file." According to the link below, Forge Viewer can deal with 60 kinds of formats. Do you mean that Forge Viewer display 3D model in SVF(2) format, whatever format of the 60 is uploaded?

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/

Comment: Exactly, and also the formats described on answer 4 without the need for translation